# Spin Button Starting at 2 Instead of 1

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have the code below which operates the spin button.  When the cell "D12" is blank and the user clicks the up button, the value in the cell starts with 2 instead of 1.  Does anyone know what I'm missing?

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
Range("D12").Value = SpinButton1.Value
SpinButton1.Max = 100
SpinButton1.Min = 1
SpinButton1.SmallChange = 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `SpinButton1.Value` is for the lack of a better word, "hidden" elsewhere. It doesn't know to reset to 1 when `D12` is blank - you should let it know to reset instead:

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
    If Range("D12").Value = "" Then SpinButton1.Value = 1
    Range("D12").Value = SpinButton1.Value
    SpinButton1.Max = 100
    SpinButton1.Min = 1
    SpinButton1.SmallChange = 1
End Sub
```